# React Confirm alert lib

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, responsive-design, alert

I'm using React confirm alert library for a delete confirmation but how do I make it responsive for all screens view , i.e for small devices ?

[image: check here the mobile view]

For a laptop and tablet it's working fine
[image: check it out]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a React confirm alert responsive on mobile, you will need to use media queries in your CSS to apply styles that are specific to mobile devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .confirm-alert {
    /* Add width or height for example */
  }
}
```